# sqlite database and languages

Tags: android

i am developping and android app in spanish and english languages

Its possible to have  differents sqlite databases in assets directory as for example the dragable-en, dragable-es with the same name?

Any help plz?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [`SQLiteOpenHelper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html), it allows you to open a database with a given name. If the database does not exist, it will create it for you (along with any table and data you might have given it).